# Ошибка при добавлении репозитория Macbuntu на Linux mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Сейчас у меня последняя версия Linux mint (19) но по какой-то причине не удается добавить репозиторий MacBuntu.
Установку производил по инструкции - https://mintguide.org/themes/649-macbuntu-theme-and-icons-mac-os-x-style-on-linux-mint.html

Так же зашел на сайт репозитория, но там такие же команды - https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему.

```
user@user-pc:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
[sudo] пароль для user: 
Вы хотите добавить следующие PPA:
 This PPA is dedicated to Macbuntu transformation pack for Ubuntu.
 Больше информации: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu
Нажмите Enter, чтобы продолжить или Ctrl+C для отмены

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.vXwPYwHLek/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F59EAE4D
gpg: key D530E028F59EAE4D: 2 подписи не проверены за отсутствием ключа
gpg: ключ D530E028F59EAE4D: "Launchpad PPA for NoobsLab" не изменен
gpg: Всего обработано: 1
gpg:              неизмененных: 1
user@user-pc:~$ sudo apt update
Игн:1 http://archive.canonical.com tara InRelease
Пол:2 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Сущ:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Игн:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Игн:5 http://linuxmint-packages.ip-connect.vn.ua tara InRelease                
Сущ:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Сущ:7 http://linuxmint-packages.ip-connect.vn.ua tara Release                  
Пол:8 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]     
Пол:9 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]   
Сущ:10 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                             
Сущ:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Сущ:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Ошк:13 http://archive.canonical.com tara Release                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Пол:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]   
Игн:15 http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/release/2.4 xenial InRelease    
Пол:17 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [269 kB]
Сущ:18 http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/release/2.4 xenial Release      
Пол:19 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [297 kB]
Пол:20 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [113 kB]
Пол:21 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [167 kB]
Пол:22 http://ubuntu.colocall.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [167 kB]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                                                 
E: Репозиторий «http://archive.canonical.com tara Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
user@user-pc:~$ sudo apt install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
E: Не удалось найти пакет macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
```

Comment: Так называемая ошибка (ваш скрин) - не работает. Измените вопрос, согласно правилам хорошего тона.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: https://uzverss.livejournal.com/3242.html

Comment: Прошу прощение, недавно зарегистрировался на данном сервисе. Информацию с консоль добавил.
PS: проблема в том, что не находит пакеты. Скорее всего не добавился репозиторий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Xubuntu 18.04 всё работает без проблем. Судя по вашим логам, некоторые репозитории недоступны, попробуйте поменять сервер репозиториев в системных настройках (с сервера вашей страны на Main Server или наоборот), это во-первых. А во-вторых инструкция устарела. То что называлось `macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7` теперь называется `macbuntu-os-icons-v1804`. Используйте команду `apt search macbuntu` чтобы узнать актуальные имена пакетов.

Comment: Сработало! Большое спасибо!
Перерыл кучу информации, так и не нашел ответа. Выручили)

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли поставить старые версии данного пакета? Так как нет нужных настроек тем в новых. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Старые версии предназначены для старых дистрибутивов и у них скорее всего зависимости от пакетов, которых нет в вашей системе. Но вы конечно можете скачать deb-пакет нужной вам версии и попытаться установить его вручную: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu/+packages